# Expected number of cards before 1st ace or 1st jack?

Tags: probability, expected-value

If a 52 card deck is randomly shuffled, and I start pulling cards one by one from the top of the deck. What is the expected number of cards I have to pull before I encounter the 1st ace OR the first jack.

Edit:
I know that for just the first ace, the answer is 48/5 + 1 = 10.6 (which is the same for the first jack). However I'm unsure if the answer is the same if the question becomes 1st ace or 1st jack. Instinctually I think the expected value is lower, but I don't really know how to justify that other than we now have 2 choices to look for instead of 1, bringing our expectation down.

Edit 2:
Ok so i get the idea that we can just treat these as 8 cards and use the similar method. The answer in that case is 44*(1/9) + 1 = 5.89. But what happens if I'm looking for the 4th jack or the 4th ace? This is a different question from the 4th jack or ace (which is 44*(4/9) + 4 = 23.56).

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a full problem statement, not relying solely on the title to carry that burden.  Including the problem setup and goal in the body of the Question gives Readers a less ambiguous description, and makes it easier to see how the context you provided illuminates your understanding of it.

Comment: It's not common to get "ace or jack" than it is to get an ace, so the expected number of cards drawn will be lower. However, there is no reason to believe that whatever technique one uses to get $10.6$ can be used this time as well.

Comment: You found the answer if $4$ cards were involved (the aces). Now $8$ cards are involved (aces and jacks). Btw, the $+1$ in your answer makes me think that the drawn ace itself is also counted. Correct?

Comment: @drhab that is correct. Ok I see what you're saying. The answer in that case is 44*(1/9) + 1 = 5.89. But what happens if I'm looking for the 4th jack or the 4th ace? This is a different question from the 4th jack or ace (which is 44*(4/9) + 4 = 23.56).

Comment: @Arthur: On the contrary, the technique is exactly the same, with 4 (number of Aces) replaced by 8 (number of Aces and Jacks). Why would it not be?

Comment: @SameerPusapaty If you are looking for the $4$-th jack then you can disregard the aces. The expectation of the number of cards drawn with the $k$-th jack as last card is $k\times\frac{52-4}{4+1}+k$

Comment: @TonyK that was a typo, sorry. I meant that it most likely is possible to use the same technique, just change the numbers a bit.

Comment: Just create a new "supercard" set called $ACEJACK$.  There are eight members in this set.  Solve the problem of finding the expected number of cards to find the first appearance in this $ACEJACK$ set.